# New version of __extends generated by TypeScript compiler

Tags: typescript

When you use inheritance, the TypeScript compiler generates the __extends function for you. Older versions of the tsc compiler generated something like this

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
```

which sets an instance of b as the prototype chain of d. That is pretty much what I would to by hand as well.

The most recent version (0.9) adds copying of property/method references which looks superflous be me:

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
```

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It now respects static properties on classes as well.

The key statment is:

```
for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
```

which will copy the parent class static members to child classes.

e.g.:

```
class Foo{
    static x = "asdf";
}

class Bar extends Foo{

}

alert(Bar.x);
```

[Try it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Foo%7B%0D%0A%09static%20x%20=%20%22asdf%22;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert%28Bar.x%29;)

The original (now closed) bug report : http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/825